# What is the difference between driver.findElement(By) and indElementByXPath(path)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What is the difference between:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]"))
```

and:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is part of the public API and is advertised and advised to use. The second one appears to be an implementation detail under this one, which public by error/ease of coding, but is not supposed to be known.

Source : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/iAf7lsj0C6k (last post)

From what is said though, no real difference in functionality, except that findElementByXPath is not available in the generic driver class, so it doesn't allow to change driver (from firefox to opera let's say) easily.

Comment: Close, but not quite. WebDriver encourages one to "code to the interface, not the implementation." The `findElementByXPath` method is the concrete implementation, and not all drivers may implement finding an element using that method. Had the original poster declared `driver` as type `WebDriver` instead of `FirefoxDriver` or `RemoteWebDriver` or whatever, the method would not have been available, and the code would not have compiled.